# Python loop to get data from every line of file and convert it to dec

Tags: python, loops

I'm kinda lost at the moment:
I have text file with lines looking like that:

```
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0035 000002ac 
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0036 000008fb
```

There are many lines like that, and I want to make script that gets the last hex value from every line and then writes them in file with output looking like this:

```
something someting hex_from_line_1 hex_from_line_2 
something someting hex_from_line_3 hex_from_line_4
```

And so on.
As I'm new to Python I have some trouble with making loop which would do this. 
Can You give me any guidance? (I'm not asking for whole loop, only guidance - I'd love to learn that, not use some finished code)

Comment: Add `exact` simple input and output. Avoid `something something` like stuffs

Comment: provide the code you have tried and the error

Comment: It's a little unclear (so the answers are coming up different). For the example input, what would the output line be? I answered assuming you really meant _last_ hex value, (so the output would be `something someting 000002ac 000008fb`), but the title might imply converting to base-10, or using all the hex after the `:`, not just the final hex term, etc. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fun thing about Python's `zip` is that it will happily take the same iterator multiple times as arguments, allowing you to pair up inputs easily. For example:

```
# For efficiency, if you're on Python 2, include this line so zip is a generator that produces pairs on demand, rather than eagerly slurping the whole file
from future_builtins import zip

with open('myinput') as f:
    # Creates a generator that produces only the final space separated value for each line (could be anything; not checking for hex)
    final_hex = (line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1] for line in f)
    # By using the same generator twice, we get the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. from one
    # and the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc. from the other.
    for hexa, hexb in zip(final_hex, final_hex):
        print("something something", hexa, hexb) # Python 3 print function
        print "something something", hexa, hexb  # Python 2 print statement
```

Note: If the input data isn't an even number of lines, this will drop the final unpaired input. You can use `itertools.zip_longest` (`izip_longest` on Python 2) if you want the unpaired value.

Comment: Sorry for providing "the whole loop", but this is one of those things that's hard to explain without an example.

Comment: Also, the title of your question seems to want to convert to decimal; if that's the case, you'd change the generator expression to parse from hexadecimal to decimal (converting to an actual `int`, since `print` will convert back for printing) with: `final_val = (int(line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1], 16) for line in f)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm kinda lost at the moment: I have text file with lines looking like
>   that:  /dev/input/event0: 0003 0035 000002ac  /dev/input/event0: 0003
>   0036 000008fb There are many lines like that, and I want to make
>   script that gets the last hex vaule from every line and then writes
>   them in file with output looking like this:  something someting
>   hex_from_line_1 hex_from_line_2  something someting hex_from_line_3
>   hex_from_line_4  And so on. As I'm new to Python I have some trouble
>   with making loop which would do this.  Can You give me any guidance?
>   (I'm not asking for whole loop, only guidance - I'd love to learn
>   that, not use some finished code)

Loop over the lines in the file like this

```
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        hexNibble=line[-1] #this is a string
        hexValue=int(hexNibble,16) #this is an integer
        #Now you have the integer value of the last hex nibble on the line
        #So...
        #Continue doing whatever you want to do with it...
```

Answer (score 0):

file.txt

```
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0035 000002ac 
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0036 000008fb
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0035 000002ad 
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0036 000008fe
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0035 000002af 
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0036 000008fg
/dev/input/event0: 0003 0036 000008fz
```

code

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = [x.split(': ')[1].strip() for x in f.read().splitlines()]

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
        f.write('something something {0}\n'.format(' '.join(data[i:i+2])))
```